# APNS push with PHP from Linux server

Tags: php, linux, ssl, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I'm having problem with using APNS with PHP on Linux server. I am using `simplepush.php` example script with this `stream_context` settings ($passphrase is set):

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert','/var/www/html/ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem');
```

and trying to connect on `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);


if (!$fp){
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
}
```

When I run the script it says:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/html/test2.php on line 27
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /var/www/html/test2.php on line 27
Failed to connect: 0
```

**Telnet test:**

```
Trying 17.172.232.46...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**Server's entrust certificates:**

```
/usr/lib/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Global_Secure_Personal_CA.pem
/usr/lib/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Global_Secure_Server_CA.pem
/usr/lib/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem
/usr/lib/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Secure_Personal_CA.pem
/usr/lib/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.pem
/usr/lib/ssl/certs/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
```

**777 permission are given on all certificates and also to `ck.pem` file which is located in the same folder as `simplepush.php` file (/var/www/html)**

Also, I believe that `ck.pem` is valid certificate, because this connections success when the call is executed from Mac terminal.

**SSL connection from terminal:**

```
azureuser@myserver:/var/www/html$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert /var/www/html/ck.pem -CAfile /usr/lib/ssl/certs/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Enter pass phrase for /var/www/html/ck.pem:
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Entrust.net, OU = www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), OU = (c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, CN = Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = "Entrust, Inc.", OU = www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference, OU = "(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc.", CN = Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Cupertino, O = Apple Inc., CN = gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
verify return:1
140195332839072:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
 1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
   i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Certification Authority/CN=Apple Root CA
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Certification Authority/CN=Apple Application Integration Certification Authority
---
SSL handshake has read 3143 bytes and written 2032 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 40C185D8F81ABD51E8BAF4BA863949A6A006AE80CEE04E2989A2E0269764A14107F0D3933E2A1A65D6825C61934F51F8
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1455228997
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Only thing that caught my eye here is this part:

```
routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
```

I read that it is some sort of bug on ubuntu version, and that it can be fixed by doing ssl downgrade, but I don't really believe if that actually can be a reason.

**Conclusion:**

- Root certificates that apns is requesting are set
- `ck.pem` is valid certificate (using password) and also absolute paths are set for certificates in the `simplepush.php` file
- `telnet` to apns is working (ports are open)
- Permissions (777) are set for `ck.pem`, `simplepush.php` and all the root certificates
- `openssl s_client ...` is returning `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` and the only suspicious thing is that `ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177`

I am missing something here (probably on my server configuration) but I ran out of ideas what it might be, and now it has become so frustrating :)

NOTE: 
I understand this topic could be a duplicate, but I searched a lot about all that associated with apns push, and read many topics related to this problem, and now I'm pretty sure that I have everything set and configured on server, but I'm still missing something.

Do you have any ideas what might cause this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm in this with you brutha.

Comment: @DavidKleiman I solved the problem by generating .pem again. I was so convinced that wasn't a problem, but I was wrong. Try to generate .pem again, hope it will solve your problem too. Regards

Comment: Thank you I will give that a try.

Comment: I tried to regenerate the .pem files to no avail. Did you generate the cert by download the certificate from apple, converting the cert and key to a .p12, and then using `openssl` to convert each of those to a .pem file?

Comment: Alrighty, I had to revoke and reissue a new apns certificate.